# What did Skyler mean by "I wish" when Jessie said "Vamonos"?

Tags: breaking-bad

In S05E07 of *Breaking Bad*, Jessie is at the car wash to retrieve the methylamine tanker, and he talks with Skyler saying "Vámonos" -- The name of the pest control company they use as face for their meth production operation.

But she says: "I wish". What did she mean by this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [What's the difference between “vamos” and “vámonos”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2327)

> When I studied Spanish I learned "let's go" is "vamos" but when I got to Mexico all I heard was "vámonos" …

So.. maybe it was said (or heard) to mean:

> Let's get this major component of meth production the heck out of the car wash. Let's Go!"

Answer (score 3):

Skyler's tendencies, particularly in the last two seasons, have a strong escapism theme to them.

With her affair, she ultimately wanted to push back at Walt, but there's a certain element of wanting to be "outside" of her marriage, if only briefly.  Her whole impetus for working with Beneke was to earn more money for Walt's treatments, but in many ways, she wanted to get out of the house, back to her old lifestyle, and to dress up.

Her cigarette smoking, weight gain, and change of hairstyle lead up to her "escape" into the pool, and there are many other examples of this as her patience with Walk grows thinner.

All this to say, when he uses the term for (roughly) "Let's Go!", I think her character development would lead us to believe that she really wishes to just get out of the whole mess and leave all of her stressors behind.

Comment: (parenthetically, I think this was actually in Season 5, but I can't remember the specific episode)

Answer (score 1):

Vamos is "let's go" vamonos is "let's leave". So basically she's saying she wishes she could leave, but the way Jesse said it is ironic since he wants to leave too, meaning he's saying "let's get out of here".

Answer (score 0):

I believe vámonos is the imperative form, i.e., vamos is "let's go" and vámonos "Let's Go!", e.g., the difference between just "let's leave" and "let's get the blazes out of here!"